# JTable passing values to excel (Text formating)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jxl, strikethrough

I use the code that you can see below in order to strike through some cells in a jtable. Works great for me, and both in appearence and in print with JTable.print() method works excellent.

```
public void strikeThrough()
{
   int rows=jTable.getRowCount();
   destroiedDocs=new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)      
     {
       String test=String.valueOf(jTable.getValueAt(i,5));
       if (test.equals("K"))
         {
          for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
            {
            String tostrike= String.valueOf(jTable.getValueAt(i, j));
            String striked=("<html><strike>".concat(tostrike).concat("</strike>       </html>"));
            jTable.setValueAt(striked, i, j);
            destroiedDocs.add(i);
            }
         } 
     }
 }
```

The problem is that when I export the resaults to excel with the jxl class I got the value in these strike through cells with the appearence

```
<html><strike>some text</strike></html>
```

instead of <strike>some text</strike> in strikethrough.
Any recomandations on how to solve this formating problem?
I pass the cells in the excel cell by cell from the jtable with loops. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAVA code:

```
String striked=("<html><strike>".concat(tostrike).concat("</strike>       </html>"));
jTable.setValueAt(striked, i, j);
```

Will work only for JAVA UI. After exporting data to excel it will show original text.
**You need to perform following steps:** 
1. Before exporting remove `<html><strike>` and `</strike></html>`. Keep original text.
2. Use following code to strikethrough cell.

Run the following code using `jxl-2.6.10.jar`

```
import java.io.File;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCell;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

public class ExcelCreate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

         WritableWorkbook workbook =
         Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
         WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Page1", 0);

         String Label[] = new String[4];
         Label[0] = "Emp ID";
         Label[1] = "Name";
         Label[2] = "Department";
         Label[3] = "Designation";

         WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
         WritableFont font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL);
         font.setStruckout(true);
         cellFormat.setFont(font);

         for (int i = 0; i < Label.length; i++) {
             Label label = new Label(i, 0, Label[i]);
             sheet.addCell(label);
             WritableCell cell = sheet.getWritableCell(i, 0);
             cell.setCellFormat(cellFormat);
         }

         workbook.write();
         workbook.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* Write your logic to handle exception. 
         */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before export each cell to the Excel you'll have to find and replace or remove the tags like

```
<html> 
    and
<strike>
```

with appropriate functions to add the required formatting..

Which API are you using to export it to Excel Format??
I think it'll be Specific the one that you're using to export to Excel.

Comment: I use the jxl library to export the resaults to it.

Comment: Yes. This seems easy part. And what about to pass this strike through on the excel because I need it!Thank you!